# Effect on JSF Datarow

Tags: jsf, effect

Is there a possibility to fire an event when a row of DataTable is rendered?

The Background of my question is, i would like to let the row or better one single cell blinking or flashing when a condiion is fullfilled.

Thougt about it would be nice to call a JS on every row.

Comment: Yeah it's possible. Where's the code you're working with?

Comment: It is just a simple JSF datatable, i haven't special code code where i tried. And it is more a general issue, cause i couldn't found any suggestions for it at google.

Comment: Does nobody has an idea of it?